# Add column if data is on the list - DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"day" : ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
                    "data" : ["01.05.2019", "05.02.2019", "10.11.2019", "15.08.2018"]})
df["data"] = df["data"].astype("datetime64")
```

And I list of datas: `list = pd.to_datetime(['01.05.2019','15.08.2018', '25.07.2012'])`

And I need to to add to df column = "col1" where:

1 where df"day" = B and df"data" is in "list"

0 otherwise

So I need result like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df["col1"] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x.day == 'B' and x.data in dates else 0, axis = 1)
#  day       data  col1
#0   A 2019-01-05     0
#1   A 2019-05-02     0
#2   B 2019-10-11     0
#3   B 2018-08-15     1
```

PD: I changed `list` to `dates`, please don't use that name.

Comment: Hmm I have error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() ?? Do you know why ?

Comment: @jack55 are you trying it with the df you posted or with another one?

Comment: @jack55 are you using `df.day == 'B'` instead of `x.day == 'B'`?

Comment: with another were x.day in ["x", "y"] and x.data in ["d1", "d2", "d3"] <-- differences

Comment: @jack55 is `x.day` a string too?

Comment: @jack55 it should work... can you show me your line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin`. And also you should add `dayfirst=True` to `to_datetime`, otherwise 01.05.2019 will turn into 2019-01-05.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"day" : ["A", "A", "B", "B"],
                "data" : ["01.05.2019", "05.02.2019", "10.11.2019", "15.08.2018"]})
df["data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data"], dayfirst=True)

li = pd.to_datetime(['01.05.2019','15.08.2018', '25.07.2012'], dayfirst=True)

df['col1'] = ((df.day == 'B') & df.data.isin(li)).astype('int')
```

Comment: there is a mistake because you do not take into consideration that "day" has to be "B" also

Comment: Updated.  Too early to post it :D

Comment: Hm I have an erro : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Are you using single `&`?  any of these scenario fits your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: df['col1'] = ((d.dftyg in ['bb, 'cc]) & df.date.isin(list)).astype('int') <-- I am trying this based on your code

Comment: `(d.dftyg in ['bb, 'cc])` this should be `isin(['bb', 'cc'])`